# Find (with proof) the domain of each of the following power series function

Tags: real-analysis

∑ nˆn . xˆn

How exactly do I do this?

Comment: Is it $\sum n^n x^n$ or something?

Comment: To proceed mechanically, use the Root Test. Less mechanically, show that if $x\ne 0$, then the terms do not approach $0$.

Comment: what is the domain of a power series?

Comment: When you use Root Test, remember to check separately the extremal values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x=0$, then the series obviously converges. We show that if $x\ne 0$, then the series does not converge.

Observe that $n^nx^n=(nx)^n$. If $x\ne 0$, then $|nx|\gt 1$ for any natural number greater than $\frac{1}{|x|}$, so $|(nx)^n|\gt 1$ for all such $n$. It follows that $n^n x^n$ does not have limit $0$ as $n\to\infty$, and therefore $\sum n^nx^n$ does not converge.

Alternately, if we already have it, we can use the Root Test.

Answer (score 1):

The radius of convergence is 0, centered on $\{0\}$. To see this, use the Hadamard root test which says that $R^{-1}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{n^n}=+\infty$, implying that $R=0$. The only point at which the series converges is $x=0$.